# Python - pickle.load() takes one positional argument (2 given)

Tags: python, pickle

This produces an error:

```
pickle.load() takes one positional argument (2 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
import pickle, os.path

created = False

phoneBook = {}
name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
while name != '':
    number = input("Please enter number: ")
    phoneBook[name] = number
    name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
    if name == '':
        print("Thank You!")

print("Your phonebook contains the following entries:")
for name, number in phoneBook.items():
    print("%s - %s" % (name, number))

while not created:
    if not os.path.isfile('phonebook.json'):
        phoneBook_Ori = pickle.load('phonebook.json', 'r')
        created = True
    else:
        phoneBook_Ori = pickle.load('phonebook.json', 'w')
        phoneBook_Upd = phoneBook_Ori.update(phoneBook)
        phoneBook_Ori.write(phoneBook_Upd)

phoneBook_Ori.close
```

Why isn't it pickling data?

Comment: Note that `pickle` does **not** create a JSON file, so you won't be able to read the pickle file by other tools that understand JSON.

Answer (score 5):

This is not how you use [`pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.load):

```
phoneBook_Ori = pickle.load('phonebook.json', 'r')
```

It takes a file object as an argument when de-serializing from a file, not strings.

Try this instead:

```
# create file object with permissions
with open('phonebook.json', 'r') as f:
    # load using pickle de-serializer
    phoneBook_Ori = pickle.load(f)
```

Saving is almost the same, make sure you have the updated `phonebook` in scope:

```
with open('phonebook.json', 'wb') as f:
    phoneBook_Ori = pickle.dump(phonebook, f)
```

As for the rest of the code, you may want to read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326725/a-user-score-saving-program/28326996#28326996) I've given that is very similar.